# Automatic deploy of new modules in Spring XD

Tags: spring-xd

Does Spring XD support automatic deployment of new modules?

Looking at the documentation, it seems that you need to restart the server to deploy a new module added in ${xd.home}/lib directory.

If not supported, is it in the roadmap?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hot detection of new modules should be working, provided that you deploy them to the `${xd.home}/modules/<type>/<name>` directory.

Please note that placing jars inside `${xd.home}/lib` should now only be needed for **classes that need to be referenced from message payloads and shared between modules**. For all other purposes, it is better to put jars needed by your custom module inside the following layout:

```
${xd.home}/
  modules/
    <type>/
      <name>/
        lib/
          your_custom.jar
          another.jar
        config/
          <name>.xml
```

By doing so, new modules (or changes to existing modules) will be picked up the next time you use them